# Can someone request restoration of parts of a deleted answer?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, deleted-answers

I posted [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/59376/5275) a while ago. I understand why an answer was deleted. However, within the discussion, there were a few comments that may serve as interesting and useful.

As a rule, can the O.P. or anyone else request that certain comments be restored while leaving the answer, overall, deleted? I've tagged this with *new feature request*, in case this feature is unavailable. If it is available, please untag.

Answer (score 6):

Comments are second-class citizens and are always subject to removal. Any important information should be in a proper post.

This I feel confident is not going to happen.

Comment: Hmm. Interesting terminology - "second-class citizens". I see your point. I guess I would have to do some copy / paste myself to compose an answer, if that made sense. BTW, thanks for deleting that answer, though the discussion was "entertaining".

Comment: @DanF I didn't delete it. It was "deleted by owner"

Comment: Right. I think you voted for deletion - vehemently. "Chazak Ve'ematz".

Comment: @DanF I don't have an unbinding deletion vote to cast. If I vote for something, it happens. Midas touch, in a way

Answer (score 1):

While, occasionally, it might make sense to provide access to comments on a deleted post so that somebody else can use them to provide or improve an answer to the question, that doesn't apply here for two reasons:

1. You have enough reputation to see the post and the comments; you already have access.
2. The vast majority of that should not see the light of day.  If the post weren't already deleted I would delete most of the comments as non-constructive.  You actually have better access now than if the post were to be restored.  (Since it was deleted by the owner, it probably won't be.)

There can be rare reasons to restore a comment that's informative (for the reason I gave).  There is no reason to restore a hostile argument.

Comment: Thanks. I was asking about a general scenario. Enjoy the Pittsburgh summer.

Comment: I attempted to answer both the general and the specific questions.  But maybe my status-declined is misplaced because that's really about the specific case; I'll remove that.  If you want to pursue the feature request you should expand on how it would work and why just being able to see them (at 10k) isn't sufficient.

Comment: I was thinking that sometimes some comments in a deleted discussion may be useful to other readers. I think in the past, I had a question were there was a useful ink in one of the comments & then the answer was deleted which takes the comments with it.

Comment: Ok, but what would the mechanism be?  Are you proposing that somebody be able to say "hey, I think there was a comment here about X; could you restore it?"?  That sounds like it would generate a lot of work (people'e memories being what they are).  If, on the other hand, you're thinking that somebody who can see the comment should be able to request its restoration, then that person has the means already to repost the useful content -- so why not just do that?

Comment: @DanF Halevai we had this feature.